# Html encoding in MVC input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, html-encode

I'm working through [NerdDinner](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf) and I'm a bit confused about the following section...

First they've added a form for creating a new dinner, with a bunch of textboxes delcared like:

`<%= Html.TextArea("Description") %>`

They then show two ways of binding form input to the model:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create() {
    Dinner dinner = new Dinner();
    UpdateModel(dinner);
    ...
}
```

or:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(Dinner dinner) { ... }
```

Ok, great, that all looks really easy so far.

Then a bit later on they say:

> It is important to always be paranoid
>   about security when accepting any user
>   input, and this is also true when
>   binding objects to form input. You
>   should be careful to always HTML
>   encode any user-entered values to
>   avoid HTML and JavaScript injection
>   attacks

Huh? MVC is managing the data binding for us. Where/how are you supposed to do the HTML encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally (but not always) want to HTML encode the values before writing them out, typically in your views, but possibly from the controller as well.

Some info here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Comment: so it doesn't matter what I let the user enter into the form, as long as I don't output it again without encoding? I don't really know how HTML injection works.

Comment: Yes. There are many types of cross-site scripting attacks, but a simple check on your own site is to try entering `<script>alert('XSS vulnerability')</script>` anywhere the user can enter data (including when creating their user name). If you see the alert popup (assuming you have javascript turned on), you'll have found a place that needs HTML encoding. It is best to HTML encode **all** output, and only remove that encoding when necessary.